# How to retrieve the selected rows from ASP.NET Form DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, webforms

I'm developing new features for an old project developped in ASP.Net Forms/VB.Net and .Net 3.5, one of this features is a batch operation which consists of letting user select multiple rows from a DataGrid (lets say it is GridA) the he press a button to start the operation, the server should display the list of selected items in another grid (lets say its GridB) in a Modal Popup (I'm using ModalPopupExtender from AjaxToolkit) the user should the fill some informations on the popup and then validate the operation using the 'Validate' Button.

So, To implement the row selection I added a TemplateColumn that display a checkbox like this:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
  <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectAll" runat="server" />
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ItemSelector" runat="server" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

The DataGrid (GridA) is bound to a dataset retrieved directly from the database.

My question is how to get the list of the selected items (on the server side) from the GridA after the user press the button 'Start' that starts the operation ?

If you have other suggestions on how to implement this scenario, your ideas are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finaly figure it out,

On the operation-button click handler I added this bit of code that allow me to identifie the selected rows and get the ID of the data item :

```
For Each item As DataGridItem In objDataGrid.Items
    Dim checkBox As CheckBox = CType(item.FindControl("ItemSelector"), CheckBox)

    If Not checkBox Is Nothing AndAlso checkBox.Checked Then
       ' My row ID is in the Third cell in an invisible column
       Dim cell As TableCell = item.Cells(2)
       If Not cell Is Nothing AndAlso cell.Text <> vbNullString Then
          ' Registering the row ID on an ArrayList to retrieve it later
          SelectedCards.Add(cell.Text)
       End If
    End If
Next
```

After that I load my selected data items from database using Ids stored on the SelectedCards ArrayList.

Good luck!